# how to run a postgres query in the unix shell script file (.sh file) and collect log for the query execution

Tags: postgresql-9.5

```
psql -U postgres
psql <<EOF
do $$

 <<block>>
begin

    alter table zdgd add column aaa date;



    create table z2 (id int);
 raise info 'ds';

 exception when others then

        raise notice 'Message --> % %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;
    exit block;
    raise info 'dsd';

end;


 $$ language 'plpgsql'

EOF
```

Comment: If query has error then it has to store the error code and where it has occured

Answer (score 0):

to save `raise` "result" to a file use `STDERR` redirect `2>`,
smth like:

```
MacBook-Air:~ vao$ psql db 2>/tmp/so <<EOF
> do \$\$
> begin
> raise notice '%', 'blah';
> end;
> \$\$
> EOF
Timing is on.
Pager usage is off.
DO
Time: 9.057 ms
```

(obviously `>` are EOF markup, not a part of DO statement
and check:

```
MacBook-Air:~ vao$ cat /tmp/so
NOTICE:  blah
```